# Can i improve this code to read and write data quicker

Tags: android, sqlite, bufferedreader

i have some sample code i have been playing around with. Basically im just reading from a csv file and writing into a table. Can the below be improved so that it goes faster seems quite slow

```
public void impcusdata() throws SQLException, IOException {
    try {

        String UnitID = getUnitID();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/mnt/sdcard/CRM.CSV");

        // Put the file into the buffer
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + CUSTOMER_TABLE);
        // Create a new string to hold the data
        String data = "";

        // Create the strings executing SQL commands for the data to be
        // inserted
        String InsertCustString = "INSERT INTO " + CUSTOMER_TABLE
                + " VALUES(";
        String InsertEndString = ");";

        // If there is any data in the .CSV file then read it.
        while ((data = in.readLine()) != null) {
            // String the results to the SQL database
            db.execSQL(InsertCustString + data + InsertEndString);
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
        String Shaw = ex.getMessage();

    }
    // log entry to the LogCat file
    Log.v(TAG, "Customer Table has been updated");
}
```

Comment: It may be improvable. But guessing bottlenecks is hard to impossible at times. Try to [measure](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/10/traceview-war-story.html) and see what's the exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [SqliteDatabase.beginTransaction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29) with [setTransactionSuccessful()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful%28%29) and [endTransaction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#endTransaction%28%29) you can combine several queries.